# Sort nodes based on ancestors

Tags: python, sorting, topological-sort

I have a problem where I would like to sort a set of nodes `{a, b, c, d}`. For each node I know the ancestors, i.e. those nodes that need to come before that node. (e.g `a: {b, c}` means that `a` needs to be somewhere in the list but after `b` and `c`).

I could solve following example iteratively like that:

1. `a: {b, c} --> b|c , a`
2. `b: {c} --> c , b , a`
3. `d: {b, c} --> c , b , d, a`

Is there a known algorithm so solve this? Preferably in Python.

Comment: Do you mean a topological ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called Topological Sort. You can see the pseudocode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Here is the python implementation:

```
import copy
def topological_sort(outcoming_edges):
    #outcoming_edges: Dict[str,Set[str]]
    # example: {'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'b': {'c'}, 'd': {'b','c'}}

    outcoming_edges = copy.deepcopy(outcoming_edges) #to make sure the original variable is not changed

    l = []

    #find outcoming_edges which has no incoming edge
    s = set(outcoming_edges.keys())
    for node in outcoming_edges:
        for ancestor in outcoming_edges[node]:
            s.discard(ancestor)

    incoming_edges = dict()

    for n, next_nodes in outcoming_edges.items():
        for m in next_nodes:
            if m in incoming_edges:
                incoming_edges[m].add(n)
            else:
                incoming_edges[m] = {n}

    while s:
        n = s.pop()
        l.append(n)

        next_nodes = outcoming_edges.get(n,set())
        while next_nodes:
            m = next_nodes.pop()
            incoming_edges[m].remove(n)
            if not incoming_edges[m]:
                s.add(m)

    if any(outcoming_edges.values()) or any(incoming_edges.values()):
        return None #graph has at least one cycle
    else:
        return l # a topologically sorted order
```

Comment: The list is outputted the other way around

Comment: just do `.reverse()` on the output list to reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [topological sort](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html#networkx-algorithms-dag-topological-sort):

```
import networkx as nx

edges = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['c'], 'd': ['b', 'c']}
G = nx.DiGraph([(k, v) for k in edges for v in edges[k]])

sorted_nodes = [*reversed([*nx.topological_sort(G)])]
print (sorted_nodes)
# ['c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
```

There's no rule that dictates the relative ordering of "a" and "d" so this should be an acceptable solution.

You can install the `networkx` library with pip.